# Get object properties with reflection except instance properties

Tags: c#, reflection, booksleeve, getproperties

I want to enumerate all object properties using reflection but i want to exclude the properties that reference objects (this should be fast enough because i'm using in a caching solution using Redis/Booksleve).

Currently i have the following but this return all the object properties including instance members:

```cs
var propertyNameAndValues = member.GetType().GetProperties().Where(m => m.GetGetMethod() != null).ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i.GetGetMethod().Invoke(member, null).ToString()));
var task = conn.Hashes.Set(db, string.Format("members:{0}", member.id), propertyNameAndValues);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overload of `GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where you can specify a `BindingFlags` argument and ensure `BindingFlags.Static` is included but `BindingFlags.Instance` is excluded.

For example:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
var properties = member.GetType().GetProperties(flags);
```

Comment: you forgot to pass the flags